# I can't get pool.map or pool.starmap to work the way I think it should

Tags: parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

So for the life of me I can't figure out which combination of pool.map() or pool.starmap() should be used to make this work as I want.  The code below executes correctly, firing off (sequentially!) two instances of runSim and appending the results.

```
results = []
argsToRun = []

for n in range(2):
    random.seed()
    env = simpy.Environment()  # Create the SimPy environment
    env.clockRate = 1e9
    argsToRun.append([env, adist, sdist, tdist, 108, intSpeed, runUntil])

for arg_list in argsToRun:
    line = runSim(*arg_list)
    results.append(line)
```

I was under the impression that something like the code below would be a simple way to run these instances in parallel (the results are not order-dependent)... but neither of them seem to work.  Surely I'm missing something obvious?

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(runSim, argsToRun)
    pool.close()
```

Nor....

```
with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(runSim, argsToRun)
    pool.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of frustration and searching, it turns out that some of my parameters were not pickleable.  This, combined with a bug in VSCode which prevented the debugger from running made it much harder to diagnose than it should have been.

Switching to the [pathos versions](https://pypi.org/project/pathos/) of Pool() solved the problem.

```
for n in range(15):
    random.seed()
    env = simpy.Environment()  # Create the SimPy environment
    argsToRun.append((env, adist, sdist, tdist, 108, intSpeed, runUntil))

with pathos.helpers.mp.Pool as pool:   ## tada!
    results = pool.starmap(runSim, argsToRun)
```